# GitHub Action (worfklow) trigger on repository creation

Tags: github, github-actions

I would like to run a specific workflow when a new repository is created, so that I can guide the user in performing an initial setup that corresponds to the standard required by the organization (i.e. setup branch protection, create an empty project with right naming convention, enable dependabot and more).

I did not find anything in the documentation to provide such level of automation, looking at the event triggers this seems not supported.

Is there anything I'm missing or do you have any idea on how I could do such things?

Comment: I'm looking for the same. So far the only thing I can come up with orchestrating this completely externally, for example, via a scheduled action that calls the GitHub REST API to interact with new repositories and such, but nothing built-in to the current actions workflow platform...